# Prerequisites for gcc-4.7.2: ppl-0.11 fails to find gmp-4.3.2

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to build prerequisites for `gcc-4.7.2`.

Both `ppl-0.11` and `gmp-4.3.2` are the recommended versions in `<gcc_src>/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/doc/HTML/prerequisites.html`

I have built and installed `gmp-4.3.2` (with `--enable-cxx` set)

Attempting to configure `ppl-0.11` fails.

```
configure: error: Cannot find GMP version 4.1.3 or higher.
GMP is the GNU Multi-Precision library:
see http://www.swox.com/gmp/ for more information.
When compiling the GMP library, do not forget to enable the C++ interface:
add --enable-cxx to the configuration options.
```

This is my configure line:

```
./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --with-gmp=$PREFIX \
    --with-gmp-prefix=$PREFIX \
```

If I look in the directory where I specified `with-gmp`, here is the installed gmp:

```
$ grep MP_VERSION $PREFIX/include/gmp*

    $PREFIX/include/gmp.h:#define __GNU_MP_VERSION 4
    $PREFIX/include/gmp.h:#define __GNU_MP_VERSION_MINOR 3
    $PREFIX/include/gmp.h:#define __GNU_MP_VERSION_PATCHLEVEL 2
```

.

```
$ l $PREFIX/include/gmp*

    $PREFIX/include/gmp.h
    $PREFIX/include/gmpxx.h
```

.

```
$ l /$PREFIX/lib/libgmp*

    $PREFIX/lib/libgmp.a
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmp.la
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmp.so -> libgmp.so.3.5.2
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmp.so.3 -> libgmp.so.3.5.2
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmp.so.3.5.2
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmpxx.a
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmpxx.la
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmpxx.so -> libgmpxx.so.4.1.2
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmpxx.so.4 -> libgmpxx.so.4.1.2
    $PREFIX/lib/libgmpxx.so.4.1.2
```

Am I missing something?

As far as I can tell, GMP is available and of the requisite version

Comment: ask on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`

Comment: The symlinks are suggesting a 3.5.2 version of GMP, not a 4.3.2 one

Comment: I just did `rm -rf $PREFIX`; downloaded `ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2`, built and installed; and `$ find . -type f | xargs grep '3.5.2'` gave this: `./libgmp.la:library_names='libgmp.so.3.5.2 libgmp.so.3 libgmp.so`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what distro you are running, have you tried to install the gmp-devel package (i.e. yum install gmp-devel on Fedora/RedHat etc)?

Comment: No, can't install devel packaged (don't have root) and have to build from source

Answer (score 1):

*PPL* will by default try to use default locations for *GMP*.  If you use *crosstool-ng*, you must do either a *cross-native* or *canadian-cross* build.  If you are doing this manually, specify `CXXFLAGS` to *PPL's* `./configure`, with a `-I<path-to-gmp-header>` and a `-Wl,-L<path-to-gmp-libs>`.  This allows the *PPL* `./configure` to find the correct version of *GMP*.

Apparently a *PPL* configure with,

```
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--with-gmp=$PREFIX \
--with-gmp-prefix=$PREFIX \
```

Is not enough.  I sleuthed  through the `./configure` script and was hacking up *crosstool-ng* before I realized that I was no longer building a *cross-compiler*, but a *canadian-cross* when I **wasn't** using my *distro* `gcc`, but another *host compiler* with a lower *glibc* shared library.  This is useful if you want your compiler to run on a larger class of machines.  It is unlikely that the *glibc* version of the build compiler will effect much.

I still had to patch `120-ppl.sh` in *crosstool-ng*,

```
do_ppl_for_build() {
...    
    ppl_cxxflags="${CT_CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD}"
+   ppl_cxxflags+=" -I${CT_BUILDTOOLS_PREFIX_DIR}/include "
+   ppl_cxxflags+=" -Wl,-L${CT_BUILDTOOLS_PREFIX_DIR}/lib "
    if [ "${CT_PPL_NEEDS_FPERMISSIVE}" = "y" ]; then
        ppl_cxxflags+=" -fpermissive"
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

So I also faced the same issue and what I did was:

1) Went inside gmp-4.3.2 folder
2) make distclean
3) ./configure --prefix=/home/sen/Documents/mingw/downloads/gmp_build --enable-cxx
4) make && make install
5) Went inside ppl-0.11 folder
6) ./configure --prefix=/home/sen/Documents/mingw/downloads/ppl_build --with-gmp-prefix=/home/sen/Documents/mingw/downloads/gmp_build --enable-cxx
7) make & make install

Took some 10-20 mins to compile and things were fine.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 0):

After years, the issue has been run into. The solution is firstly to download last version of gmp. Then, copy the path as in like the picture. Don't forget to `./configure` with `--enable-cxx`, which is really important point. `./configure --enable-cxx`. Now time is to ppl installation, `./configure -help` indicates that `--with-gmp=DIR          search for libgmp/libgmpxx in DIR/include and DIR/lib`. So write `./configure --with-gmp=<<dir of gmp as shown in first picture, you may have a different path>>`

[image]

I wrote, respectively, `./configure --with-gmp=/usr/local/include`, `make`, `sudo make install`  then it works like a charm!

[image]